# ajax not working on ipad

Tags: jquery, ajax, ipad, safari

I have a form:

```
<form id="orderForm" onsubmit="return prepareOrder(this);" action='@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EpayLogonUrl"]' method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="Signed_Order_B64" value="">
         <input type="hidden" name="email" size="50" maxlength="50" value="@Model.Email">
         <input type="hidden" name="appendix" value="@Model.AppendixInfo">
         <button class="wiz_button" type="submit" disabled="disabled">
         <span><span id="buy_button_name">Buy</span></span></button>
</form>
```

and a function PrepareOrder

```
function prepareOrder(form) {
    var selectedPayWay = $('.pay_cont.selected').data('way');
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Pay/CreateOrder',
        data: { payWay: selectedPayWay },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.IsSuccess) {
                switch (selectedPayWay) {
                    case payWay.Terminal:
                        showBookingInfo(response.BookingId, response.ExpiredDate);
                        result = false;
                        break;
                    case payWay.Epay:
                        $("input[type=hidden][name=Signed_Order_B64]").val(response.SignedString);
                        $("input[type=hidden][name=appendix]").val(response.AppendixString);
                        result = true;
                        break;
                }

            } else {
                toastr.options.timeOut = 10000;
                toastr.info(response.Message);
                result = false;
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            result = false;
        },
        async: false
    });

    return result;
}
```

The problem is that on a new ipad (Safari) `CreateOrder` action is not called. On the desktop browser, it works fine. There are no errors in console. I tried to add an alert after:

```
success: function (response) {
```

like that:

```
success: function (response) {
alert(response.IsSuccess)
```

and `alert` return me `true`. Why? if `CreateOrder` is not called. I also added logging to `CreateOrder` action and there are no output strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari and/or Ipad support a very strong caching. I had the same problem in my application, too. Try adding following attributes to your controller (or even base controller):

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
```

Comment: I have java based web application, so where i add the Output cache ...?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this iOS Safari issue reproduced only in some versions. For me iPad with iOS 6.0.1 has this redundant caching, but on 6.1.2 has no.
As a workaround I'm using fake data to force Safari not to look into its cache:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Pay/CreateOrder',
    data: { payWay: selectedPayWay, fakeDataToAvoidCache: new Date()},
    success: function (response) {
               //logic goes here
    });
```

Basicly, It's weird, that Safari caches POST request which must not to be cacheable, according to the specification.