# Ajax Request not working on iPad 1 (iOS 5.1.1)

Tags: jquery, html, ios, ajax, ipad

I'm running an iPad web app and want to reload some content through a get request, it works perfectly in browser, but does not work at all in Safari on the iPad 1 (iOS 5.1.1) anyone have any ideas?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

           var count = 0;

        var getMeeting= function() {
            $.get('MeetingInfo.aspx', function(data) {
                $('#room').html(data);


            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            getMeeting();
        });
        setInterval(getMeeting, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191744/ajax-not-working-on-ipad?rq=1

Comment: Have turned caching off globally using   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); and its not working :(

Comment: have you tried to use the debugger so that you can see any js errors that are being issued if at all any. This might  help solve any issues

Comment: Theres no debugger in this version of iOS :(

Comment: This works FINE on the iPad 2

Comment: Is your page/tab is visible then you checking timer? iOS Safari stop any timer then page/tab is hidden.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, I wasn't referencing jQuery properly (I didn;'t have internet connectivity and it was referencing to a CDN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a plonker...

Referencing an external jQuery file and I only had network access not internet access.

Sorry all

Answer (score 1):

Try with nocache get param via timestamp:

```
var getMeeting= function() {
    $.get('MeetingInfo.aspx?' + (new Date()), function(data) {
        $('#room').html(data);
    });
};
$(function () {
    getMeeting();
});
setInterval(getMeeting, 5000);
```