# Responsive design menu issue only iPhone

Tags: jquery, css, iphone, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having an issue with the Bootstrap(v3.0.1) menu dropdowns on iPhone. i got 2 menus. Left button works fine but right menu doesn't work. 
When I resize the browser on a desktop, it all works fine. But when I tried it from a mobile browser (I tried it on chrome on an iPhone), I didn't see the right menu :

You can see the live web page here: [website](http://imomomega.com)

Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

edit for code:

```
 <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-user-nav-div">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
```

menu sidebar

```
<div class="sidebar">
                      <div class="navbar-collapse  navbar-user-nav-div in" style="height: auto;">

<ul id="menu-slider" class="navbar-sidebar-nav ">
        <li id="menu-item-0" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-0 dropdown">
            <a href="#" title="Gebelik Öncesi" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" id="7" onclick="return clickBaseLink();">
                <i>
                    <img src="http://lab.basarbilisim.com/imom/Media/Gebelik Öncesi.png" style="width: 82px;height: 63px;"></i>
                <span>Gebelik Öncesi</span>
            </a>
            <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" style="right: -142px;">
                    <li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-100">
                        <a title="Gebeliğe Hazırlık" href="/Home/Menu/8">
                            <span>Gebeliğe Hazırlık</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-100">
                        <a title="Yardımla Üreme Teknikleri" href="/Home/Menu/9">
                            <span>Yardımla Üreme Teknikleri</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1 dropdown">
            <a href="#" title="Gebelik Dönemi" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" id="12" onclick="return clickBaseLink();">
                <i>
                    <img src="/Media/Gebelik Dönemi.png" style="width: 82px;height: 63px;"></i>
                <span>Gebelik Dönemi</span>
            </a>
            <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" style="right: -208px;">
                    <li id="menu-item-200" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-200">
                        <a title="Hafta Hafta Gebelik" href="/Home/Menu/13">
                            <span>Hafta Hafta Gebelik</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-200" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-200">
                        <a title="Gebelikte Beslenme" href="/Home/Menu/14">
                            <span>Gebelikte Beslenme</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-200" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-200">
                        <a title="Gebelikte Egzersiz" href="/Home/Menu/15">
                            <span>Gebelikte Egzersiz</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-200" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-200">
                        <a title="Çoğul Gebelik" href="/Home/Menu/16">
                            <span>Çoğul Gebelik</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-200" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-200">
                        <a title="Gebelikte Psikoloji" href="/Home/Menu/17">
                            <span>Gebelikte Psikoloji</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-200" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-200">
                        <a title="Gebelikte Cinsellik" href="/Home/Menu/18">
                            <span>Gebelikte Cinsellik</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-200" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-200">
                        <a title="Gebelikte Bakım" href="/Home/Menu/19">
                            <span>Gebelikte Bakım</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-200" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-200">
                        <a title="Gebelikte İlaç Kullanımı" href="/Home/Menu/20">
                            <span>Gebelikte İlaç Kullanımı</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-200" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-200">
                        <a title="Tanısal Testler ve Ultrason" href="/Home/Menu/21">
                            <span>Tanısal Testler ve Ultrason</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-200" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-200">
                        <a title="Gebelikte Aşılar" href="/Home/Menu/22">
                            <span>Gebelikte Aşılar</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-200" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-200">
                        <a title="Gebelikte Yaşanabilecek Kritik Durumlar" href="/Home/Menu/24">
                            <span>Gebelikte Yaşanabilecek Kritik Durumlar</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2 dropdown">
            <a href="#" title="Doğum ve Sonrası" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" id="25" onclick="return clickBaseLink();">
                <i>
                    <img src="/Media/Doğum ve Sonrası.png" style="width: 82px;height: 63px;"></i>
                <span>Doğum ve Sonrası</span>
            </a>
            <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" style="right: -125px;">
                    <li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-300">
                        <a title="Doğuma Hazırlık" href="/Home/Menu/26">
                            <span>Doğuma Hazırlık</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-300">
                        <a title="Doğum Belirtileri" href="/Home/Menu/27">
                            <span>Doğum Belirtileri</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-300">
                        <a title="Doğum Yöntemleri" href="/Home/Menu/28">
                            <span>Doğum Yöntemleri</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-300">
                        <a title="Emzirme" href="/Home/Menu/29">
                            <span>Emzirme</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-300">
                        <a title="Bebeğin Gelişimi" href="/Home/Menu/30">
                            <span>Bebeğin Gelişimi</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    <li id="menu-item-000" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-000 dropdown">
        <a title="Albüm" href="/Home/MyAlbums" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i>
                <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/album.png"></i>
            <span>Albüm</span>
        </a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" style="right: -125px;">
            <li id="menu-item-439" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-439">
                <a title="Yeni Ekle" href="/Home/AlbumAdd">
                    <span>Yeni Ekle</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-449" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-449">
                <a title="MyAlbums" href="/Home/MyAlbums">
                    <span>Albüm Listesi</span>
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
    function clickBaseLink() {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
</script>

                      </div>                    
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Add your necessary css and jquery code here in the question that what did not work...

Comment: thank you for response. Can you check on iPhone that website link? It works perfectly everywhere except iPhone. Button has data-target=".navbar-user-nav-div"

Comment: sorry, can't until you post the relevant code...

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in my Windows phone and should be a cross-browser issue! [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4853528/3726246).